# How to use Python Pandas isin() in the context of an IF statement

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, isin

Having some trouble working out the issue here and could use some advise.

```
col_list = ['Task1','Task2']
        
if new_temp_df['Task Type'].isin(col_list):    ### THIS IS THE OFFENDING LINE!

     temp_list2.append(new_temp_df['Job Number'])
     results2_df = results2_df.append({
                            'Job Number': new_temp_df['Job'],
                            'Task1': 'Yes',
                            'Task1 Runs': new_temp_df['Runs'],
                            'Task2': 'Yes',
                            'Task2 Runs': new_temp_df['Runs'],
                            'Campaign-level Match': 'Yes',
                            }, ignore_index=True)

else:
    pass ..........
```

I keep getting the error:

**ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().**

I've tried variants to suit (based on abit of googling), for example

```
if new_temp_df['Task Type'].isin(col_list).all()
```

and

```
if np.where(new_temp_df['Task Type'].isin(col_list))
```

No joy.

**Desired End Goal**

1. To read in a dataframe where all the values in field 'Task Type' are checked against the list provided in [col_list].
2. If both those values in the [col_list] variable are present - TRUE, If not: FALSE
3. Have that evaluated at the IF statement level - return the bool value (and hopefully all just get on with our lives happily ever after)

Please, any ideas would be great. I see isin() used in all capacities but not in an IF statement - very interested to know the method.

Thanks all in advance

Comment: It seems you need the other way around, `np.isin(col_list, new_temp_df['Task Type']).all()` ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i tried if ```np.isin(col_list, new_temp_df['Task Type']).all():``` and got the same response: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 0):

`any` can be used in `if conditional`.

Toy example:

**Input Setup**

```
col_list = ['Task1','Task2']

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Task Type':['Test1', 'Task1'],
    'val':[1,2]
})
df
```

**Input df**

```
Task Type   val
0   Test1   1
1   Task1   2
```

**Code**

```
if any(df['Task Type'].isin(col_list)):
    print('task')
```

**Output**

```
task
```

Comment: Hi there Utsav - thanks for the answer. I tried ```if any(new_temp_df['Task Type'].isin(col_list)):``` and unfortunately it still bombs out, same error.

Comment: Would you please share sample of `new_temp_df`?